Cross-ratio for more than 4 points on a line
It is known that the pairs $(\mathbb{P}^1,4 \mbox{ points})$ are classified by a $1$-dimensional family, parametrized by cross-ratio (up to an action of $S_3$). I would like to ask if the same is true for higher number of points, that is, is there some $(n-3)$-dimensional family parametrizing all pairs $(\mathbb{P}^1,n \mbox{ points})$, up to an action of some finite group on the base?
To be more precise, here is an example in case $n=4$, and a question for genral $n$.
Example: Let $B=\mathbb{P}^1\setminus \{0,1,\infty\}$, let $X=\mathbb{P}^1\times B$, let $f\colon X\to B$ be the second projection. Let $D\subseteq X$ be the sum of three lines $\{z\}\times B$, $z\in \{0,1,\infty\}$, and a diagonal $\{(x,x):x\in B\}$. Write $X_b=f^{-1}(b)$, $D_b=D|_{X_{b}}$. Now $f\colon (X,D)\to B$ is a smooth family, such that every pair $(\mathbb{P}^1,4 \mbox{ points})$ is isomorphic to some fiber $(X_b,D_b)$, and two fibers $(X_{b},D_{b})$, $(X_{b'},D_{b'})$ are isomorphic if and only if $b$ and $b'$ belong to the same orbit of the action of $S_3=\operatorname{Aut}(B)$, i.e. if and only if the cross-ratios of $(0,1,\infty,b)$ and $(\sigma(0,1,\infty),b')$ are equal for some permutation $\sigma\in S_3$.
Question: is there is a smooth family $f\colon (X',D')\to B'$, over some $(n-3)$-fold $B'$, such that every pair $(\mathbb{P}^1,n \mbox{ points})$ is isomorphic to some fiber $(X'_{b},D'_{b})$, and $B'$ admits an action of some finite group $G$ such that two fibers $(X'_{b},D'_{b})$, $(X'_{b'},D'_{b'})$ are isomorphic if and only if $b$ and $b'$ belong to the same $G$ orbit?
I was trying to take $B'=B^{n-3}\setminus \{x_i=x_j \mbox{ for some } i\neq j\}$, $X=\mathbb{P}^1\times B'$, and for $D$ the sum of $\{z\}\times B'$, $z\in \{0,1,\infty\}$, and $\{(x_{i},x_{1},\dots,x_{n-3})\}$ for $i=1,\dots,n-3$. Now every pair $(\mathbb{P}^1,n \mbox{ points})$ is isomorphic to some fiber $(X'_{b},D'_{b})$, but I have a problem checking when two fibers are isomorphic (I am pretty sure that there are only finitely many fibers isomorphic to a given one, but I would really like to see some structure, like a group action as above).
I am working over an algebraically closed field, preferably of any characteristic (but $\mathbb{C}$ is fine, too).

Yes, such a family exists, its base is usually denoted $\mathcal{M}_{0,n}$ and is called the moduli space of genus $0$ curves with $n$ marked points. It can be constructed as follows: take the projective space $\mathbb{P}^{n-3}$ with $n - 1$ points in general position, say
$$
x_0 = (1:1:\dots:1:1),\quad 
x_1 = (1:0:\dots:0:0),\quad\dots\quad
x_{n-2} = (0:0:\dots:0:1),
$$
and let $\mathcal{M}_{0,n}$ be the complement of the union of linear spans of all collections of $n-3$ points among the $x_i$.

Thank you! Just to make sure I get it right: $(\mathbb{P}^{1}, n \mbox{ points})$ corresponding to $x_{n-1}\in\mathcal{M}{0,n}$ is the unique rational normal curve $C$ passing through $x_0,\dots,x{n-1}$, and the group action on $\mathcal{M}{0,n}$ is given by $S{n-1}\to\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^{n-3})$, sending $\sigma$  to the unique automorpism mapping $x_{i}$ to $x_{\sigma(i)}$. Is there an easy way to see the "universal" family $X\to \mathcal{M}{n,0}$ whose fiber over $x{n-1}$ is isomorphic to $(C_x,{x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}})$? Do you have some reference where this is plainly written?

See Kapranov, M. M., Veronese curves and Grothendieck-Knudsen moduli space $M_{0,n}$. J. Algebraic Geom. 2 (1993), no. 2, 239–262.
